# enter key event in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im using jQuery too. Im trying to call one method keyPressEvent on pressing enter button. Whats wrong in the code

```
var AplOperations = function() {
  // this function i want to call when an enter button is pressed
  this.keyPressEvent = function() {
      // my code goes here
  }
} 

var myOpr = new AplOperations();

document.onkeyup = myOpr.keyPressEvent();
```

Comment: There is a comma after `}` .`//this.keyPressEvent = function() {
        // my code goes here
      }**,**`

Comment: Edited. Thats not the problem

Comment: @DipakDelvadiya, first of all, the function itself is not firing up

Comment: @jakeehoffmann, I just want to fire the function once I press enter button

Comment: Ok, added my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick function runs automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425397/onclick-function-runs-automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the keyup and execute your things in callback. Right now it executes when the script gets execute.

```
   document.onkeyup = function () {
        myOpr.keyPressEvent();
   }
```

[**Updated Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/L3djqyxc/1/)

Comment: Are you able to get the alert of test? Im not able to get the alert on pressing enter.

Comment: @SyedSha See, in the fiddle, you are not owner if complete document. You should be inside the output document.

Comment: So what should I do to test in order in the fiddle. Plz let me know. I hope this will be working fine in my code. I can test it tomorrow.

Comment: got it. Thx Accepting your answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `()` after `myOpr.keyPressEvent`, other wise the function will be executed intermediately.

Working example: (click first on the panel for the focus)

```js
    var AplOperations = function() {
      // this function i want to call when an enter button is pressed
   
      this.keyPressEvent = function() {
          // my code goes here
          var elem = document.getElementById("test");
          elem.innerHTML += "key pressed<br>"
      }
    } 

    var myOpr = new AplOperations();

    document.onkeyup = myOpr.keyPressEvent;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: @Thanks Julian. A bit late than ANS.

Comment: 8 seconds indeed. Have to type less before I post

Comment: @Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

`document.onkeyup = myOpr.keyPressEvent();`

Using brackets immediately calls the function and the result is assigned to the `onkeyup` handler. If you remove the brackets your function will be assigned as a handler