# How do I pass custom function inside .map function on newly created element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am populating a `<ul></ul>` with `<li></li>` using `fetch` method api request.

The ul looks like the code below:

```
<ul id="todos" class="collection">
</ul>
```

The script that populates the todos:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/todos")
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((data) => {
  let todos = data;
  return todos.map(todo => {
    let liTodo = createNode("li");
    liTodo.innerHTML = '<button class="btn-small remove-todo" onclick="' + deleteTodo(`${todo._id}`) + '">Delete' + '</button>';
    liTodo.classList.add("collection-item");
    append(ulTodos, liTodo);
});

function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element); // Create the type of element you pass in the parameters
}

function append(parent, el) {
  return parent.appendChild(el); // Append the second parameter(element) to the first one
}

function deleteTodo(id) {
  console.log("deleteTodo function called " + id);
}
```

[image]

**Problem:**
Upon loading the page and checking `console`, I can see that `deleteTodo()` function is invoked even though I did not click it.

Do you know how can I properly pass the `deleteTodo()` with the `id` **only** when it is clicked?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A relevant question exists for this problem, for solutions please check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425397/onclick-function-runs-automatically

Comment: bind the event with addEventListner instead of inline functino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using another function wrapper by using **ES6 backticks** for the entire button element.

This way the function will not get invoked before the event, since it's considered a string.

Look here a working example:

```js
const ulTodos = document.getElementById('todos');

function myFetch() {
  let todos = [{id:1, text: "a"}, {id:2, text: "b"}, {id:3, text:"c"}];
  
  return todos.map(todo => {
    let liTodo = createNode("li");
    liTodo.innerHTML = `<button class="btn-small remove-todo" onclick="deleteTodo('${todo.id}')">Delete</button>`;
    liTodo.classList.add("collection-item");
    append(ulTodos, liTodo);
  });
}


function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element); // Create the type of element you pass in the parameters
}

function append(parent, el) {
  return parent.appendChild(el); // Append the second parameter(element) to the first one
}

function deleteTodo(id) {
  console.log("deleteTodo function called " + id);
}
  
  
myFetch();
```

```html
<ul id="todos" class="collection"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this. You answer works for a static data. In my case, I am fetching data from mlab(MongoDB) and you answer did not work.  I am getting undefined for each ID when I click the button

Comment: Maybe you have put the wrong identifier for id, don't forget underscore `_id` before id. I removed it in my example :)

Comment: Yeah :) Glad it helped! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the `deleteTodo` unknowingly. Wrap the on click invocation in an arrow function.

```
liTodo.innerHTML = '<button class="btn-small remove-todo" onclick="() => deleteTodo(' + `${todo._id}` + ')">Delete' + '</button>';
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this but it is still invoked inside the loop

Comment: @redshot My bad, updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to an arrow function.

Instead of

```
function deleteTodo(id) {
  console.log("deleteTodo function called " + id);
}
```

Use

```
const deleteTodo = (id) => {
  console.log("deleteTodo function called " + id);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this helps, the problem is at invocation time...

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this but it is still invoked inside the loop

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Actually, I would recommend you the react way of doing this. You are creating elements with string. Instead, you should create them with JSX (react way) by using 'map' function. That would be more accurate and resolve your problem.

Comment: @BurakGavas I'm currently only using ES6 for this. In react, the solution is just to wrap the deleteTodo(id) in an anonymous arrow function inside the map function

Comment: I mean in your return function you should have a JSX expression like:
`
items.map((item, idx) => 
    <li key={idx}>
        // your button and its function here
    </li>
)
`
You should write this inside your JSX

Answer (score 1):

When you concat innerHTML like this:

```
'...click="' + deleteTodo(`${todo._id}`) + '"...'>
```

The function `deleteTodo` is called immediately, which returns `undefined`.

And actually the innerHTML you got is:

```
<button class="btn-small remove-todo" onclick="undefined">Delete</button>'
```

So, do not call it, just take it as string.

```js
liTodo.innerHTML = `<button class="btn-small remove-todo" onclick="deleteTodo(${todo._id})">Delete</button>`;
```